# How to update single column in flutter sqflite?

Tags: database, flutter, dart, sqflite

**This are my columns**

```
await db.execute('CREATE TABLE LocalProduct('
          'id INTEGER,'
          'name TEXT,'
          'price TEXT,'
          'image TEXT,'
          'qty INTEGER,'
          'product_item_count INTEGER,'
          'last_fetched DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'
          'created_at DATETIME)');
      var _flag = storage.getItem("isFirst");
```

**This is my query**

```
final res = await db.rawUpdate('UPDATE LocalProduct SET qty = ? WHERE id = ?', [podDAta.qty,podDAta.id]);
```

** This is the data that is coming from the api and the one that should be updated **

```
{
            "id": 2877,
            "name": "Britannia Cheese Block, 200g",
            "qty": 9,
            "created_at": "2021-04-20T11:30:08.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-04-20T11:30:08.000000Z"
        },
```

*i only want to update the qty of that id, but i am getting 2 errors.*

1. the data in the db is been deleted or isnt there anymore.
2. it doesnt update.

so can i not update the qty only?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the ID you are trying to update does not exist in the table. Make sure that `podData.id` exists in `LocalProduct` table, because it looks like the UPDATE command is fine.

In know this should be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: the id is there in the db, because this data have been fetched earlier, its just that the qty is not getting updated instead the db is cleared.

Comment: what do you mean by the db is cleared? all of the data is deleted or just the doc with the proper id you are trying to update?

Comment: What do you get if you query `final result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT name FROM LocalProduct WHERE id=?', [podDAta.id]);` ?

Comment: i get an empty array [] when i run the update query

Comment: i mean the data is [] when run the 

`final result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT name FROM LocalProduct WHERE id=?', [podDAta.id]);`
`
after the update query

Comment: so that's why you get an error when you try to update, it does not exist. Maybe you should import your data again to your db, try the rawQuery command and if you get a result, then try to do the rawUpdate. If you import your data again and rawQuery return [], means that you are not importing correctly you data to the table.

Comment: the data is there inside the db because the api sends only the items that are inside the db, what you said is right too but here, mines a different case